# List from django view past to template is not showing any elements

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a problem in Django. I made the following view passing a list of errors and a length of the error list.

[image]

The list of errors consists of strings. Output from printing it before passing it can be seen below.

[image]

In my template I have the following code.

[image]

But for some reason, the ordered list has no instances when rendering the page.

[image]

I'm probably doing something wrong but cannot seem to figure out what.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Remove ":" from "recommended_errors:" in the view :)

Comment: Hahahaha omg, sometimes you just overlook the most simple thing. xD Thanks mate!